# Google Analytics collect data of Age & Gender by submiting form

Tags: forms, google-analytics, universal-analytics

Google Analytics provide a feature that can analyze "Age" & "Gender" of visitors. But my customer want to track these data by submiting a form after checkout successfully.

**That form looks as follow:**

```
<form id="form-checkout" class="form-success" method="post"  action="">
        <ol class="fs-fields">
          <li class="gender">
            <label><?php echo $this->__('Gender') ?></label>
            <div class="fs-radio-group fs-radio-custom clearfix fs-anim-lower">
              <span><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" /><label><?php echo $this->__('Male')?></label></span>
              <span><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" /><label><?php echo $this->__('Female')?></label></span>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="ages">
            <label><?php echo $this->__('Ages') ?></label>
            <select name="ages">
              <option value="< 20"><?php echo $this->__('< 20') ?></option>
              <option value="20-35"><?php echo $this->__('20-35') ?></option>
              <option value="35-50"><?php echo $this->__('35-50') ?></option>
              <option value="> 50"><?php echo $this->__('> 50') ?></option>
            </select>
          </li>
        </ol>
        <div class="button-box">
          <button class="fs-submit fs-show" type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('submit') ?>" onclick="sendDataToUa();"><span><?php echo $this->__("Back to Home")?></span></button>
          <button class="fs-submit fs-show" type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?>" onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>'"><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

**Js script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function sendDataToUa(){
    var gender = jQuery('input[name=gender]:checked', '#form-checkout').val();
    var ages = jQuery('#form-checkout option:selected').val();
    ga('set', 'dimension1', gender);
    ga('set', 'dimension2', ages);
    ga('send', 'pageview', {
      'dimension1': gender,
      'dimension2': ages,
    });
  }
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

My tracking code look like:

```
<script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-64495311-1','auto');

                            ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
                            ga('set', 'dimension1', 'male');
        ga('set', 'dimension2', '< 20');
        sendDataToUa();
        ga('send', 'pageview', '/popupstore');

    </script>
```

I'm waiting for report data on google analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in Google feature imports data for recognized visitors from other Google Services (GDN mostly, I think), so this will not help you here (you cannot add demographic data yourself).

You need to create custom dimensions in your property settings (session or user scope - hardly any visitor will change gender and age between hits) and send them along with an interaction hit. Implementation details depend on your setup so I just refer you to the [documentation for custom dimensions and metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#collection), and then you may get back to us with any specific question that might come up.

Comment: I'm confusing of using "custom variables" or "customer dimensions". Are you sure"custom dimensions" is better ?

Comment: Custom variables do no longer exist in the current version of Google Analytics (Universal Analytics), even if the menu item is still present (needs to be to display historical data). Custom dimension work somewhat different than custom vars, but for your purpose that does not matter.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. It really helpful. I've tried many ways with custom variable but get no result.

Comment: I've just updated my progress. Could you take a look please ?. I'm struggling in implement custom dimension.

Comment: I've just found the problem, I should using "dimension1" instead of "gender". But currently, I'm not sure that GA collected my data or not.

Comment: It takes at least 24 hours (and up to 48, in my experience) for custom dimensions show up the first time. Your code should work. You are setting the dimension twice - the "set" methods sets the value for all subsequent interactions, if you set a configuration object as parameter to your pageview only that specific pageview gets associated with the dimension (so doing both does make much sense).

Comment: Thank you Eike, I'm waiting for update in Google Analytics report. There is one thing make me confused: I've choose my dimension's scope is "Hit". In my case, is it correct ? or should I use another scope ?

Comment: I have been waiting for 40 hours and my report is still empty :(. Not sure my script is correct or not.

Comment: 100 hours but still not getting result :(

Comment: Just to be sure, where exactly are you looking ? Custom Dimensions do not show up in the standard reports, you either need a custom report or select them as a secondary dimension.

Comment: I created a custom report: "gender" as dimension, "session" as metric.

Comment: Can you share a Url to your site ?

Comment: http://magebuzz-dev.com/popupstore/  You can see the gender form after completed checkout. (Choosing pay with cash on delivery method). It's just my dev site so you can checkout free.

Comment: You have two sets of tracking codes. The one  for which you set the dimensions is wrapped in a function (sendDataToUa) which is never called. You need to either execute your sendDataToUa function (which will track pageviews to your confirmation page double, since there is already a pageview in the head section of the page) or set the dimensions before the Analytics code in the head is executed.

Comment: I've just updated the tracking code. Not sure it's correct or not.